# XRG: How to minimize?

Tags: macos, monitoring

[XRG](http://www.gauchosoft.com/Products/XRG/) system monitor is awesome!

But I can't figure out how to minimize it. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Any ideas?

iMax
El Capitan 10.11.3
XRG 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you like the app…

To minimize the XRG window, just double-click on the title bar.  This will be either on the top or right side of the window depending on which graph orientation you are using.